# WebService JAX-WS não funciona no WebSphere 8.5

Tags: jax-ws, http-status-code-404, websphere-8

When making the call a webservice on WebSphere 8.5 I get the following error message:

Error 404: java.io.FileNotFoundException: SRVE0190E: File not found: / AutenticacaoAutorizacaoWSService

some activation is required JAX-WS or some setting specifies the Momente the deploy?

In the development environment using the LibertyProfile works normally.

Comment: Check via admin console, if your application is successfully installed and started. You may check, if JAX-WS service is visible via Services > Service providers > service_name

Comment: He does not appear in "Service providers", the application in which this service works normally built only what not. For him the apparatus article "Service providers", which is to be done?